# Latin teacher via email

Tags: teaching-method

Is there a school or group of people where you can have a teacher of Latin by email?

I know there is *Accademia Vivarium Novum*, where you can go and learn Latin by immersion into the language, but I think it requires a considerable investment of money and time.

The method I would be looking for would be writing an email in Latin and receiving an answer from the teacher and also the correction. Also that you can ask for translations if you don't know how to say something. The topics would be more modern things rather than focusing on translation of ancient authors or something like that.

Does such a system exist? What could be the price?

If that does not exist, is there a site where you can have a penfriend in Latin?

Answer (score 3):

This is perhaps not what you request, but it might make up for what you need: a Latin-friendly chat room! Indeed, there are at least three that I am aware of, one being in this site. They are free, and cannot assure you of always a response, or immediate help, but at least you can try your Latin!

- "##Latin": this IRC chat room can be accessed online [here](http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=##Latin). You can write both in English and Latin, asking for help too.
- "##Latinitas": this IRC chat room can also be accessed online, [here](http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=##Latinitas). You are asked to only write (and "well enough to be understood") in Latin, so it's more advanced that the one above.
- "Latin.Stackexchange": this is the local chatroom, available [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=latin.stackexchange.com) (select CONLOQVIVM). I get the impression it is not as highly visited as the others.

Now, if you are still interested in an email conversation, you can go to the first chat room and ask for someone willing to take part on it. If you are willing to pay, maybe you can motivate someone to become your email-friend for a bit of Latin exchange!

Comment: [Our site's chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36130/conloqvivm) is indeed a good place. The activity level varies quite a lot, but if you want to speak, it's not that hard to find someone to chat with. Just drop in and say hi. There won't be any paid services within the room, but you might find someone who is willing to help you for some compensation. And to some extent people will also help you without any compensation – that's what this site is all about.